# How can get current portlet request in spring bean?

Tags: request, portlet

Portlet was created as GenericPortlet not Spring MVC portlet.

I need get current portlet request in my bean. Is there way to achive it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
RequestAttributes attrs = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
if (attrs instance of PortletRequestAttributes){
    PortletRequest request = ((PortletRequestAttributes) attrs).getRequest();
}
```

Comment: It works only when I create portlet as Spring MVC portlet, but doesn't for simple GenericPortlet

Comment: What about just pass portlet request to bean from doView/processAction methods?

Comment: Yes, I do it now like this way. But I wonder do it without passing request as argument of bean or metods parameter.

Comment: I think you can try use ThreadLocal<PortletRequest>, but this way you also need pass current request to threadLocal. No difference between pass request to bean except and this way, but thread local way request become available everywhere in current thread.

Comment: Hmm... Interestingly, thanks, I think I can put request in entry point of my generic portlet... 'll try